# Custom helper for <picture> CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am still learning about CakePHP and I want to create a custom helper for a picture tag. I already used and made one for < source > but now I can't figure out how to wrap it inside the < picture >. It should be solved with some sort of array I assume, including 3 < source > and 1 < img >.

The View:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<picture>
    <?= $this->Picture->source($article, 'photolg_dir', 'photolg', '1200px'); ?>
    <?= $this->Picture->source($article, 'photomd_dir', 'photomd', '992px'); ?>
    <?= $this->Picture->source($article, 'photosm_dir', 'photosm', '768px');?>
    <?= $this->Picture->img($article, 'photo_dir', 'photo'); ?>
</picture>
```

The Custom helper where I create the < source > and want to add the < picture >

```
<?php
 namespace Cake\View\Helper;

 use Cake\Core\Configure;
 use Cake\Http\Response;
 use Cake\View\Helper;
 use Cake\View\StringTemplateTrait;
 use Cake\View\View;


 class RestHelper extends Helper
 {

     use StringTemplateTrait;

     public $helpers = ['Url'];

     protected $_defaultConfig = [
         'templates' => [
             'link' => '<a href="{{url}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</a>',
             'image' => '<img src="{{url}}"{{attrs}}/>',
             'source' => '<source srcset="{{url}}"{{attrs}}/>',
         ]
     ];

     public function __construct(View $View, array $config = [])
     {
         parent::__construct($View, $config);
         $this->response = $this->_View->response ?: new Response();
     }

    public function link($title, $url = null, array $options = [])
    {
        $escapeTitle = true;
        if ($url !== null) {
            $url = $this->Url->build($url, $options);
            unset($options['fullBase']);
        } else {
            $url = $this->Url->build($title);
            $title = htmlspecialchars_decode($url, ENT_QUOTES);
            $title = h(urldecode($title));
            $escapeTitle = false;
        }

        if (isset($options['escapeTitle'])) {
            $escapeTitle = $options['escapeTitle'];
            unset($options['escapeTitle']);
        } elseif (isset($options['escape'])) {
            $escapeTitle = $options['escape'];
        }

        if ($escapeTitle === true) {
            $title = h($title);
        } elseif (is_string($escapeTitle)) {
            $title = htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES, $escapeTitle);
        }

        $confirmMessage = null;
        if (isset($options['confirm'])) {
            $confirmMessage = $options['confirm'];
            unset($options['confirm']);
        }
        if ($confirmMessage) {
            $options['onclick'] = $this->_confirm($confirmMessage, 'return true;', 'return false;', $options);
        }

        $templater = $this->templater();

        return $templater->format('link', [
            'url' => $url,
            'attrs' => $templater->formatAttributes($options),
            'content' => $title
        ]);
    }

    public function image($path, array $options = [])
    {
        $path = $this->Url->image($path, $options);
        $options = array_diff_key($options, ['fullBase' => null, 'pathPrefix' => null]);

        if (!isset($options['alt'])) {
            $options['alt'] = '';
        }

        $url = false;
        if (!empty($options['url'])) {
            $url = $options['url'];
            unset($options['url']);
        }

        $templater = $this->templater();
        $image = $templater->format('image', [
            'url' => $path,
            'attrs' => $templater->formatAttributes($options),
        ]);

        if ($url) {
            return $templater->format('link', [
                'url' => $this->Url->build($url),
                'attrs' => null,
                'content' => $image
            ]);
        }

        return $image;
    }

     public function source($path, array $options = [])
     {

         $path = $this->Url->image($path, $options);
         $options = array_diff_key($options, ['fullBase' => null, 'pathPrefix' => null]);

         if (!isset($options['alt'])) {
             $options['alt'] = '';
         }

         $url = false;
         if (!empty($options['url'])) {
             $url = $options['url'];
             unset($options['url']);
         }

         $templater = $this->templater();
         $source = $templater->format('source', [
             'url' => $path,
             'attrs' => $templater->formatAttributes($options),
         ]);

         if ($url) {
             return $templater->format('link', [
                 'url' => $this->Url->build($url),
                 'attrs' => null,
                 'content' => $source
             ]);
         }

         return $source;
     }

     public function implementedEvents()
     {
         return [];
     }
 }
?>
```

Another Helper where I connect between view and the RestHelper:

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\View;

/**
 * Bild helper
 */
class PictureHelper extends Helper
{
    public $helpers = ['Rest', 'Html'];
    /**
     * Default configuration.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_defaultConfig = [
    ];

    public function picture(\App\Model\Entity\Article $article)
    {

    }

    public function source(\App\Model\Entity\Article $article, $dir, $size, $brpnt)
    {
        return $this->Rest->source('/' . $article->$dir . '/' . $article->$size, ['class' => 'img-fluid', 'alt' => 'Responsive image', 'media' => "(min-width: $brpnt)"]);
    }

    public function img(\App\Model\Entity\Article $article, $dir, $size)
    {
        return $this->Rest->image('/' . $article->$dir . $article->$size, ["class" => "img-fluid"], ["alt" => "Responsive image"]);
    }


    public function thumb(\App\Model\Entity\Article $article, $dir, $size)
    {
        return $this->Rest->image('/' . $article->$dir . '/' . 'thumbnail-' . $article->$size, ["class" => "img-fluid"], ["alt" => "Responsive image"]);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Your code example seems to be broken...

Comment: I added the rest of the code. This one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a Solution. Just check if the columns with the pictures you want to use in the < picture > are filled or not, and then call the source function.
To slim this down a bit more just save the path as a hole in the DB instead of like i did storing the folder and name separately.

The Helper:

```
class PictureHelper extends Helper
{
    use StringTemplateTrait;

    public $helpers = ['Html', 'Url'];

    protected $_defaultConfig = [
        'templates' => [
            'source' => '<source srcset="{{url}}"{{attrs}}/>',
        ]
    ];

    public function source($path, array $options = [])
    {

        $path = $this->Url->image($path, $options);
        $options = array_diff_key($options, ['fullBase' => null, 'pathPrefix' => null]);

        if (!isset($options['alt'])) {
            $options['alt'] = '';
        }

        $url = false;
        if (!empty($options['url'])) {
            $url = $options['url'];
            unset($options['url']);
        }

        $templater = $this->templater();
        $source = $templater->format('source', [
            'url' => $path,
            'attrs' => $templater->formatAttributes($options),
        ]);

        if ($url) {
            return $templater->format('link', [
                'url' => $this->Url->build($url),
                'attrs' => null,
                'content' => $source
            ]);
        }

        return $source;
    }

    public function thumb($what, $dir, $size)
    {
        return $this->Html->image('/' . $what->$dir . '/' . 'thumbnail-' . $what->$size, ["class" => "img-fluid"], ["alt" => "Responsive image"]);
    }

    public function picture($what, $large, $largedir, $medium, $mediumdir, $small, $smalldir, $xsmall, $xsmalldir)
    {
        //
        if (!empty($what->$large)) {
            $lg = $this->source('/' . $what->$largedir . '/' . $what->$large, ['class' => 'img-fluid', 'alt' => 'Responsive image', 'media' => "(min-width: 1200px)"]);
        } else {
            $lg = NULL;
        }

        if (!empty($what->$medium)) {
            $md = $this->source('/' . $what->$mediumdir . '/' . $what->$medium,['class' => 'img-fluid', 'alt' => 'Responsive image', 'media' => "(min-width: 998px)"]);
        } else {
            $md = NULL;
        }

        if (!empty($what->$small)) {
            $sm = $this->source('/' . $what->$smalldir . '/' . $what->$small,['class' => 'img-fluid', 'alt' => 'Responsive image', 'media' => "(min-width: 768px)"]);
        } else {
            $sm = NULL;
        }

        $img = $this->Html->image('/' . $what->$xsmalldir . $what->$xsmall, ["class" => "img-fluid"], ["alt" => "Responsive image"]);

        return "<picture> $lg $md $sm $img</picture>";
    }
}
```

In the View:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <?= $this->Picture->picture($article, 'photolg', 'photolg_dir', 'photomd', 'photomd_dir', 'photosm', 'photosm_dir', 'photo', 'photo_dir'); ?>
</div>
```